# Best way to scan emails for a code with a large amount of regex'es

Tags: regex, string, .net-core, stringbuilder

I'm designing a .NET Core project which should scan emails for package tracking codes. I'll probably have +500 regex expressions which represent the different code formats of all the different postal services.

The only approach I can come up with is splitting the email body into pieces on every space or non-numeric or non-alphabetic character, and then run that through my array of regex expressions.

The splitting as well as the regex comparing seems so inefficient CPU-wise, but I can't come up with a more performant approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the package tracking code occures only once per email?
Would it make sence to try out the regexes from most to least probable?

Comment: No, a quick estimate is that about 1 out of every 50 emails has multiple codes. But trying the regex'es from most to least probable is a great tip! I know the destination country so I can sort the regex'es to try those which belong to a certain country first. Some edge cases will have to run through the whole array, but thus looks like a great improvement. Thanks!